Random character loss when filling input form by a barcode scanner
I have a website that is build in ASP.NET that contains different input fields.
Some of the input fields are filled using barcode scanner devices.
From time to time it happens that characters are randomly missing.
For e.g.: Scanning the same barcode 100x times produces 99x times the code "LE010101" and once the code "LE01011" (in the last case a 0 is missing).
It only happens when the scanner output is put into the input form.
If I use the scanner 1000 times and paste the output in a textpad window, the error never occurs. (Different browsers like IE, Chrome, etc. were tested and always the same result)
The input form is generated by ASP.NET and looks like this:
<input class="form-control input-block-level valid" data-val="false" data-val-required="The Barcode field is required." id="Ident" name="Ident" type="text" value="" datal-val="false" aria-describedby="Ident-error" aria-invalid="false">

Any ideas what could be wrong?
